# python - List only directories, insert absolute path

Tags: python

I'm currently using `os.walk` to list only the directories in a given folder. However, I need the absolute path for each directory listed.

My line of code:

```
folder_path = '/Users/username/Desktop/T'

array2 = next(os.walk(folder_path))[1]

print(array2)
```

It outputs:

`['T1', 'T2', 'T3']`

How can I get the absolute path of each directory?

The result I'm looking for would be:

`['/Users/username/Desktop/T/T1', '/Users/username/Desktop/T/T2', '/Users/username/Desktop/T/T3']`

Comment: use os.path.abspath(filename) to get absolute path

Comment: his `os.cwd` is actually his desktop I am guessing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined `os.path.abspath` and `os.path.join`:

```
folder_path = '/Users/username/Desktop/T'

array2 = next(os.walk(folder_path))[1]
array3 = []

print(array2)
# ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']

for local_folder in array2:
    array3.append( os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder_path, local_folder)))

print(array3)
# ['/Users/username/Desktop/T/T1', '/Users/username/Desktop/T/T2', '/Users/username/Desktop/T/T3']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for current,dirs,files in os.walk(...):
    for folder in dirs:
        print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current,folder))
```

if you just want the directories in `T`

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir,join as pjoin
root = "/Users/username/Desktop/T"
print [pjoin(root,p) for p in listdir(root) if isdir(pjoin(root,p))]
```

Comment: This lists the absolute path, but for all sub-folders and files that are in `folderpath`, but I only need it for folders from the depth I'm (at `folderpath` only). Even is `T1` has files and sub-folders, I need the absolute path of `T1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    for o in array2:
        print os.path.abspath(o)
```

Comment: This lists the folders with the absolute path of the script I'm running (`/Users/username/Desktop/script.py`), not the absolute path from the `folder_path` directory ==> `/Users/username/Desktop/T1` when it should be `/Users/username/Desktop/T/T1` as my `T1` sits inside the `T` folder.